# Why does the X value of a rotation behave differently from Y and Z on Unity objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I have the following code:

```
private void Update()
{
    Vector3 currRotation = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
    currRotation = new Vector3(currRotation.x + 2, currRotation.y, currRotation.z);
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(currRotation);
}
```

Whatever the script is attached to will rotate around the X-axis.

I'm not interested in using other ways to rotate the object as this is a small model of how I'm handling the rotation of an object in an application I'm creating.

when I add the "+1" to the Y and Z coordinates it continues to rotate, however, when it's on the X it behaves differently. When X passes the 90 degree mark and is set it appears to subtract from 90 instead of continue to add it.

So when I set X to 94, the next time I read X it's 86.

Why does it do this?

Comment: I believe your problem has to do with Gimbal Lock. https://answers.unity.com/questions/573035/avoiding-gimbal-lock.html

Comment: That is exactly my problem. Thank you for finding that answer for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem your seeing is an issue due to Gimbal Lock.  Check out the following:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/573035/avoiding-gimbal-lock.html

Comment: transform.Rotate(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), 2.0f); solved my problem.